# Parsing Line Breaks in Mash Linkedin Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The output from my mash has \n\n included but when I extract the data, none of the line breaks are parsed.

This is what I'm using:

```
<%= @user.linkedin_token.callback.summary %>
```

How can I get the line breaks included?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by using simple_format. that was easy!

```
<p><%= simple_format @user.linkedin_token.callback.summary %></p>
```